# convert ionic datetime to hour and min

Tags: javascript, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic date time component as below

```
  <ion-item >
                    <ion-label>Time:</ion-label>
                    <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" pickerFormat="h mm A" [(ngModel)]="localEstDelTime"></ion-datetime>
              </ion-item>
```

on ionViewDidLoad i am setting the value of localEstDelTime as:

```
var d = new Date()
 var dt = d.setTime(d.getTime() + (5.5 + 2)*60*60*1000)
this.localEstDelTime = dt.toISOString()
```

basically 5.5 hours has been added to make it for indian time zone which is GMT + 5.5  and for this use case the time is supposed to be shown plus 2 hours of current time.

now, the requirement is let's say end user added another extra hour through UI then i want to get that hour and time in the local time zone. My code does not work properly as below:

```
 var storeEstDelTime =  Date.parse(this.localEstDelTime)
 var date = new Date(storeEstDelTime)
 var hours = date.getHours() + 5.5
 var minutes = date.getMinutes()

        var ampm = Number(hours) >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour ’0′ should be ’12′
        var minutesStr = Number(minutes) < 10 ? '0'+ minutes : minutes;

        estDeliveryTime = hours + ':' + minutesStr + ' ' + ampm;
```

so i need estDeliveryTime to be just hh:mm AM/PM format. my above code need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to convert your date to `UTC time set` always as it is a common standard. Like for input date, just convert the date like this:

```
var now = new Date(),
    utcDate = new Date(
        now.getUTCFullYear(),
        now.getUTCMonth(),
        now.getUTCDate(),
        now.getUTCHours(),
        now.getUTCMinutes(), 
        now.getUTCSeconds()
    );
```

Now, when you take input from user for delivery time(for that extra hour), do the same thing to that date, and add that hour to the `utcDate` and in the end, convert the UTC date to GMT date with 5.5 as for IST.

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

1. npm i --save date-fns
2. import {format} from "date-fns" in your .ts file
3. let example_time = "2019-11-30T14:42:30.951+08:00";
4. format(new Date(example_time), "HH:mm");
5. console.log(example_time) => '14:42'